# Global dynamic reconfigure over multiple nodes

Tags: dynamic-reconfigure

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everybody.

I am facing a difficulty designing a dynamic reconfigure node.

My package's configuration consists of three nodes, each one with a dynamic reconfigure of its own.

I would like to have parameters common to all three nodes, which are changed in all of them by accessing and modifying some kind of "global" dynamic reconfigure parameter regime.

Is something like this possible?

Thank you in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/154906/global-dynamic-reconfigure-over-multiple-nodes/) by [li9i](https://answers.ros.org/users/12651/li9i/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2014-04-18

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hoping that you have seen the tutorials at http://wiki.ros.org/dynamic_reconfigure/Tutorials

I ll first create a single global_param.cfg file and add the global and local parameters in that.

I ll make sure that the header file is added in different nodes where I want to change the parameters.

In the specific nodes, I will access only the variables/parameters that are used to change the values.

I guess that in this way a single configure file can be used to change the parameters across nodes.

---

Originally posted by [sai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2967/sai/) with karma: 1935 on 2014-04-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [li9i](https://answers.ros.org/users/12651/li9i/) on 2014-04-19**:
Hi Sai and thank you.

Why oh why didn't I think of this?

Due to a last-moment architectural change in my package, I will not be needing a global parameters file right now.
Nevertheless, your solution is elegant and I will test it in my spare time.